# How to use Selenium with PHP?

Tags: php, selenium, web-testing, headless-browser

I'd like to use Selenium to automate a few web tasks (not for testing). I think I have Selenium RC Server installed, but have no way of writing "test scripts" since I can't find a client driver in PHP (see: http://seleniumhq.org/download/).

Is there a way for me to use Selenium with PHP? This seems to suggest I need PHPUnit http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html. I just want to automate a few tasks, not get involved with a full suite of testing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try Following things

1. Get Phpunit installed and working
2. Also have JAVA sdk & jre on your pc.
3. Now record test cases using selenium IDE.
4. Export the testcases to php files.
5. Using these exported functions create an library of test cases.
6. Create suite which calls the functions/tests from library.
7. Now to execute Start Selenium Server using java command.
8. Using phpunit Execute the suite.

for refrence how to write these files click [here](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/631-Integrating-PHPUnit-with-Selenium.html) and also try on git hub

Comment: The [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) library is simply enough, and the set-up can be even easier with tools like [Steward](https://github.com/lmc-eu/steward). I would suggest not to waste time with Selenium IDE and simply write the desired scenario right in PHP.

Comment: The answer here is showing its age a lot now. In 2019, there's no need for any Java involvement. You never did need PHPUnit to use Selenium - it's a tool for running tests not for browser automation. Both Selenium and the W3C standard for web automation are based on a REST API, so having a library helps - but its just about making http requests - e.g. see https://makandracards.com/makandra/49096-how-to-control-chromedriver-using-curl

Comment: This is link http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/631-Integrating-PHPUnit-with-Selenium.html return 404 - not found.

Comment: This answer is too old below answer is better solution for now a days

Answer (score 22):

[facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) is an awesome client for selenium and php.

You can use it to automate web tasks (as the OP wanted), or you can simply integrate php-webdriver to your testing framework. There are some project already providing this:

- [Steward](https://github.com/lmc-eu/steward) integrates php-webdriver directly to [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/).
- [Codeception](http://codeception.com) testing framework provides BDD-layer on top of php-webdriver.
- You can also check out this [blogpost](http://codeception.com/11-12-2013/working-with-phpunit-and-selenium-webdriver.html) + [demo project](https://github.com/DavertMik/php-webdriver-demo), describing custom [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) integration.

---

## Install Everything

1. Download and install [facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver). `composer require facebook/webdriver`
2. [Download Selenium](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) & Start it. `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-#.jar`
3. [Download Quick Java](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/quickjava/) and place it into your project directory.

---

## Usage

In this example, we use the extension `quickjava` to disable everything except `javascript` and `cookies`.

View more preference settings here:
https://github.com/ThatOneGuyDotNet/QuickJava/blob/master/defaults/preferences/defaults.js

View more example commands here:
https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/Example-command-reference

```php
use Facebook\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxProfile;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

// Change this to the path of you xpi
$extensionPath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../bin/selenium/quickjava-2.0.6-fx.xpi';

// Build our firefox profile
$profile = new FirefoxProfile();
$profile->addExtension($extensionPath);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.curVersion', '2.0.6.1');
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Images', 2);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.AnimatedImage', 2);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.CSS', 2);
//$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Cookies', 2);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Flash', 2);
$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Java', 2);
//$profile->setPreference('thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.JavaScript', 2);
$profile->setPreference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Silverlight", 2);

// Create DC + Driver
$dc = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$dc->setCapability(FirefoxDriver::PROFILE, $profile);

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $dc);
$driver->get('http://stackoverflow.com');

// Do stuff - https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/Example-command-reference
//$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("element-id"));

// The HTML Source code
$html = $driver->getPageSource();

// Firefox should be open and you can see no images or css was loaded
```

Comment: Note: facebook/php-webdriver was renamed to php-webdriver/php-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

You need the selenium server running and a web driver library to interact with it.

Officially selenium has no support for PHP but in Nearsoft we created a library to interact with the Json Wire Protocol. We aimed to make it as similar as possible to the examples from other languages and drivers from the official site so an example from the page in Java would have a very similar syntax in php.

Check it out: https://github.com/Nearsoft/PHP-SeleniumClient

If you like it, share it, get involved, fork it or do as you please.

Regards, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

I think the guy asked mainly how to use IDE generated files.

There is a formater for PHP: You then just have to export as PHPunit.

Selenium IDE: PHP Formatters :: Add-ons for Firefox
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-php-formatters/

Comment: That doesn't support the Selenium IDE v2 I believe