# Selenium and Chrome (or other browser) setup on linux for PHP

Tags: javascript, php, linux, google-chrome, selenium

I need to traverse a website with a crawler (goutte or mink, whichever), but I need to login. To login, I need to execute javascript.

I've done the research, and there is phantom.js but it does not support linux install. So I tried doing it with firefox and chrome.

After I install chrome, It gives me this message

```
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver
system property
```

With firefox, It tells be that there is no output display.

For that error, I couldn't find the solution. There are many, but none of them work.

I now this is a short explanation of the question, but I've spent the entire day trying to make this work, and I'm stuck.

If you have some suggestions about a different browser, possibly that has been made specifically for this pourpuse, please, do tell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724778/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-in-chrome#answer-13729517 look at the top answer here

Comment: Thanks, but I need that in PHP. Where would I put the Java code for Selenium to see it? I already found those solutions but they are not in PHP

Comment: maybe something like this: http://codeception.com/11-12-2013/working-with-phpunit-and-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: or use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590360/how-to-use-selenium-with-php