# browsing pages behind login system php-phantomjs

Tags: php, authentication, php-phantomjs

**Scenario :**

I have a target website that I need to crawl and take a screenshot of the personal account feed.

**Needs :**

1. Login to the website.
2. Browse to the personal area.
3. crawl the page.

**Code :**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

    $client = Client::getInstance();
    $client->getEngine()->setPath('C:\xampp\htdocs\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe');
    $client->getProcedureCompiler()->clearCache();
    $client->isLazy();
    $delay = 15; // 5 seconds
    $width  = 1366;
    $height = 768;
    $top    = 0;
    $left   = 0;


    $request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createCaptureRequest();
    $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();
    $request->setDelay($delay);
    $request->setTimeout(10000);


    $data = array(
    'login' => '***',
    'password' => '***',
    );

    $request->setMethod('POST');
    $request->setUrl('login-url');
    $request->setRequestData($data); // Set post data
    $request->setOutputFile('screenshot.jpg');
    $request->setViewportSize($width, $height);
    $request->setCaptureDimensions($width, $height, $top, $left);

    $client->send($request, $response); 

    $file = fopen("1.txt","a");
    fwrite($file,$response->getContent());
    fclose($file);
```

**Question :**

How to browse to the personal page URL without loosing the cookies and the session ?

I have already tried to only change the setUrl another time on the same request, but it's not working.

```
    $request->setMethod('GET');
    $request->setUrl('personal-page-url');
    $request->setOutputFile('screenshot1.jpg');

    $client->send($request, $response);

    $file = fopen("2.txt","a");
    fwrite($file,$response->getContent());
    fclose($file);
```

Comment: do you have to use phantom-js? only if you web page has JS you need it.

Comment: @mortezakavakebi my web page is using JS , so I have to use phantom-js

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issue on github](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/issues/124)
, there is still an unfixed problem with cookies. you can follow it.

> Cookie and php-phantomjs #124  Open   lucl22 opened this issue on Oct 1,
>   2016 · 3 comments

Or you can use other ways of scrapping if your target webpage doesn't have so much ajax data transmission like:

- [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte)
- [httpful](https://github.com/nategood/httpful)
- [guzzle](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests%20https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)
- [php-vcr](http://php-vcr.github.io/)

---

if you realy need js to be run you can use other web-drivers for php

- [how-to-use-selenium-with-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590360/how-to-use-selenium-with-php)
- [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver)

Comment: The issue is not about browsing on same cookies , it's about the cookies management, and my target website is using js

Comment: added some replacement. bacause phantom-js really had that problem unsolved.