# How to web scrape HTML Table using PHP

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, dom

I am trying to scrape the table from the following link and place into an array.

https://www.tradingview.com/markets/currencies/cross-rates-overview-prices/

I have tried various ways, just cannot get it right.

```
<?php

$htmlContent = file_get_contents("https://www.tradingview.com/markets/currencies/cross-rates-overview-prices/");
    
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);

$Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');
$Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

//#Get header name of the table
foreach($Header as $NodeHeader) 
{
    $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
}
//print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table without header name as key
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail) 
{
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
    $i = $i + 1;
    $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
}
//print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table with header name as key and outer array index as row number
for($i = 0; $i < count($aDataTableDetailHTML); $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < count($aDataTableHeaderHTML); $j++)
    {
        $aTempData[$i][$aDataTableHeaderHTML[$j]] = $aDataTableDetailHTML[$i][$j];
    }
}
$aDataTableDetailHTML = $aTempData; unset($aTempData);
print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();
```

This is the error output: (Note, there are quite a few lines of these errors)

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag svg invalid in Entity, line: 405 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\scraper.php on line 6

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag path invalid in Entity, line: 405 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\scraper.php on line 6

Warning: Undefined variable $aDataTableDetailHTML in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\scraper.php on line 30

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\scraper.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\scraper.php on line 30

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looking at that page I'd say the content is loaded and updated by a web socket. If so, the data won't be in the page you download with PHP.

Comment: I just did a test with a random page with a table in it, and it worked fine. https://www.theguardian.com/football/premierleague/table. I am figuring the same, as i inspected the code and it fetches the data elsewhere and is constantly changing.

Comment: Could this answer help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090728/3710053

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed thank you for the suggestion. I added the code and it seems it only clears the errors. Still not displaying the table. I can display the headers and all the div's on that website when i add it to the code. Yet only the table does not want display.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. The errors are from validating the html. Take a look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090728/3710053) how to deal with that.
2. The actual html where you are interested in (the table-data) are not present in the source-html. They are created via JavaScript somehow. To deal with that kind of pages you could use i.e. Selenium. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33659892/3710053) on how to do that in php.